# How to make WCF service run continuously in IIS?

Tags: wcf, iis, msmq, wcf-binding, msmq-wcf

I've written a small wcf service application which reads messages from msmq. And hosted the wcf service in IIS-7. THe issue is I can read the message only if I click on browse button from IIS. There is no client application which refers this service uri. I need wcf service to run automatically and continuously all the time.

Is it possible to run the WCF service hosted in IIS continuously without any user interaction ?

Answer (score 2):

When you host anything in IIS,it always run continuously unless your site is idle.IIS has a default setting where the site is idle for more than 20 minutes,it will shutdown the site.This setting is at the application Pool advanced settings as shown below

[image: Application Pool Idle Timeout]

> You can set Application Pool Idle time out to zero so that it never
>   shuts down

Also wondering how exactly have you written the logic to pull the data from the MSMQ service.In case you have not looked into the details, Running a recurring background job is not straightforward in [WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354953/good-way-to-run-recurring-background-task-in-wcf) or Asp.net .If you are using timer thread,it may not work all the time. **if you are using something like  [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) ,then it fine**.But you have to make sure that it can fine all the time and check all edge cases like [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238566/wcf-service-best-way-to-accept-requests-from-a-client-and-do-background-work)

So the take away is

> if you need a background task, use a Windows Service instead.Or you use something like [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [this nuget](https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder) and with IdletimeOut to 0 in corresponding Application Pool

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was working with Microsoft support it looks like we can host the wcf service in 3 ways. 1. Initialization Module (IIS 8 or above). 2. Using Task Scheduler(specific exe project). 3. Power Shell   We have both types of client who are using IIS7 & 8. Not sure what is the recommended way for IIS7. As of now I'm not using any threading mechanism. Also, I never worked on hangfire. I will go through your article and will see.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the application pool to be running continuously? This means at the least disabling all recycling mechanisms, setting idle timeout to 0, and setting Start Mode == Always.

You'd probably benefit from using the [Application Initialization](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) module to ensure the service remains activated all the time.

Comment: Thank you. As per your suggestion I tried Application Initialization module in IIS8 and changed the Advanced setting's Idle timeout to 0 and start mode to always. Now after recycling it reads the message immediately. Is there is any other configuration I need to change when I host WCF service in IIS8 or above. I am just trying to figure out the standard procedures to follow. I didn't find any article on this.